# Overflow position of child element being applied to window on refresh

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I have a search results page in a React app where the user can select filters, which in turn updates the query params of the URL and causes a re-mount in React. One issue I'm running into, across multiple browsers, is that if any my filters are within overflow-y containers, then the position of the child overflow is applied to the window on re-mount. Here's an example:

1. Scroll within a child div that contains a checkbox (let's say 70% of the way down the div)
2. Click on a checkbox filter
3. Component will re-mount
4. Regardless of where the main window scroll location was set previously, the main window is now scrolled down 70% the way.

I've tried [setting restoration to manual](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2015/09/history-api-scroll-restoration), but that doesn't do anything. I've also tried to grab the scroll position manually, with `window.scrollY` and similar functions, and restore it to that position, but it returns the scroll position of the child element.

Comment: ```window.scrollY``` is readonly. Try scrolling up with ```window.scrollBy(0, 0)``` after the remount which sets x and y.

Comment: To clarify, I wasn't trying to set `window.scrollY`, I was taking its position and setting `window.scrollTo()` to its position. I'd also like the window to remain in the same position it was already in.

Comment: I missed the part where you're scrolled within a child div. What parts of the app are remounting? Just the content of the child div or also outside?
But you're also saying you set ```window.scrollTo()``` to it's position. I think you want the ```offsetTop``` of the checkbox and set the ```scrollTop``` of the of the child div the checkbox is in.

Comment: Thanks for the follow-up. I ended up using `window.history.pushState` to push new query params without causing re-renders.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `window.history.pushState` allows query params to be updated without forcing a re-render.